# javascript django html tags

Tags: javascript, html, django

```
var articles = [
    {% for article in article_list %}
        {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
        {
            title: "{{ article.title }}",
            slug: "{{ article.slug }}",
            content: "{{ article.content }}",
            authors: [
                {% for author in article.authors.all %}
                     {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
                     {
                     first_name: "{{ author.first_name }}",
                     last_name: "{{ author.last_name }}",
                     }
                {% endfor %}
            ]
        }
    {% endfor %}
    ]
]
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',articles);
```

This is code located in calendar-conf-events.js(fullcalendar), and cause error
I passing objects to index.html ( which use calendar-conf-events.js )
And, In JS I use objects and template tags, but error

Error is : "identifier or string literal or no numeric literal expected" 
Cause at {%

Comment: And what, exactly, *was* this error?

Comment: Is this in a `.js` file? If so you cannot use template tags in a `.js` file. You can move your javascript code into an `.html` Django template and wrap the javascript in `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use template tags in a `.js` file like this.

The way I personally have handled this type of situation is to move my JS code into a Django template, and wrap it in `<script></script>` tags:

```
<script>
var articles = [
    {% for article in article_list %}
        {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
        {
            title: "{{ article.title }}",
            slug: "{{ article.slug }}",
            content: "{{ article.content }}",
            authors: [
                {% for author in article.authors.all %}
                     {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
                     {
                     first_name: "{{ author.first_name }}",
                     last_name: "{{ author.last_name }}",
                     }
                {% endfor %}
            ]
        }
    {% endfor %}
    ]
]
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',articles);
</script>
```

It sounds like you might be able to move this code into `index.html` if that is where you are accessing `articles`.

## Update:

Since your JavaScript uses jQuery, make sure to load that library ahead of time the same way you would do it elsewhere. For example, you could add the following inside your `<head></head>` tags at the top of your template:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, But
"$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',articles); "
Cause Error "(index):363 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"